# Is it possible to include a library at compile time but exclude it or not copy it after

Tags: java, compiler-construction, gradle

I have a library that is a stub library, so it contains methods that are not implemented but it is just used for the development environment and for the compiler to expect these methods, however the complete library will be available later after compilation.

Is there a way in gradle to include this external library only during compilation but exclude it or remove it later (so that it doesnt replace the existing library)?

what I currently have is this (below), but that copies the stub library over and replaces the original library.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'ext-libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

How can I modify this code to allow the explained functionality?

Comment: In which following task would you like it to be excluded?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the stub library that I want to exclude is in that folder ext-libs and it is called let's say "stublib.jar"

Comment: By default, the java plugin compiles your sources and makes a jar from the compiled classes and resources. And that's pretty much it. The compile classpath is only used to compile the sources. So, where in the build is it a problem to have this library in the classpath?

Comment: Have you tried using the `provided` scope instead of `compile`? Should be available starting from plugin version 0.8.0.